# How can I speed up a query that uses a cursor?

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to build a SQL query that does a DateDiff on two subsequent rows in a table of timestamps. The query shows how many milliseconds are in between the timestamps. My initial solution uses a cursor to get the rows. However, this is slow especially since I'm dealing with rows in excess of 170k. Here's the query:

```
declare cur cursor for
select timestamp from TimeStamps
declare @firststamp datetime2
declare @secondstamp datetime2
fetch next from cur into @firststamp
while (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
begin
    fetch next from cur into @secondstamp
    print(DateDiff(millisecond, @firststamp, @secondstamp))
    set @firststamp = @secondstamp
end
close cur
deallocate cur
```

Is there a way I can speed this up?
Also, is there an alternative query I can write to get the desired results?

Comment: You have tagged the question "mysql", yet you are using SQL Server syntax.  Please tag correctly.

Comment: Do you have an auto increment field defined in that table?

Comment: @Shadow , yes, the table has an auto increment field. How would you have approached it? I'm curious to know how your solution would differ to Gordon's

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SQL Server 2012+, you can do this using `lag()`:

```
select t.*,
       datediff(millisecond, lag(timestamp) over (order by timestamp),
                timestamp) as diff_ms
from t;
```

Based on the syntax of the query in the question, I am ignoring the database tag.

Comment: Worked like a charm!! Thanks a lot :)